# Whats the use of "&" , 0x000000FF , >> 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, uicolor

Whats the use of  **&**, **0x000000FF** and  **>> 8** in the following method. Can any one explain?

Thanks in advance

```
(UIColor *)UIColorFromIntegerCode:(int)integerCode  {    
    CGFloat r = (integerCode & 0x000000FF) / 255.0f;
    CGFloat g = ((integerCode & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255.0f;
    CGFloat b = ((integerCode & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0f;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: Well which operator are you stuck with? What happens when you google it and read the documentation?

Comment: Get the color's components in a bitwise fashion

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

Comment: `&` means AND. `&` is binary AND, `&&` is logical AND.

Comment: @Sulthan `&` is better known as bitwise AND, not binary AND.

Comment: @rmaddy right, that's me writing fast from mobile.

Comment: I don't completely blame them for asking. Swift passes itself off as a "first, easy" lang. Then hides memory implementation details. Then next thing they give you a bit-shift and throw you back into raw memory.

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** There is a little bug in your. Here is the edited version:

```
- (UIColor *)UIColorFromIntegerCode:(int)integerCode  {
    CGFloat b = (integerCode & 0x000000FF) / 255.0f;
    CGFloat g = ((integerCode & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255.0f;
    CGFloat r = ((integerCode & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0f;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0f];
}
```

**Explanation:**

**& is the Bitwise AND Operator:** It takes two numbers and performs AND operation on every bit. The resultant bit is 1 if both bits are 1 otherwise 0.

**>> is the Bitwise Right Shift Operator:** It takes two numbers. First is the number that will be shifted. Second is the places to shift.

`0x000000FF` is the hexadecimal representation of blue color. Performing a bitwise AND between `integerCode` and `0x000000FF` filters the blue bits from the integerCode and assigns it to float b.

Similarly `0x0000FF00` is the hex of green and `0x00FF0000` is the hex of red.

Notice the shifting of `FF` between the three hex values.

0x000000**FF** 
0x0000**FF**00 (shifted 8 bits right)
0x00**FF**0000 (shifted 16 bits right)

The bitwise right shift operator is used to adjust this shifting of bits.
Finally filtered value is divided with 255 to make it between 0 and 1. (255 is the maximum value a particular color can have.)

After filtering the colors in r, g and b, they are provided to UIColor method to create a UIColor.

If you are further interested in the details of bitwise operators, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-facts-bitwise-operators-c/) is a good resource.

Comment: By the way, the expression can be also written as `((integerCode >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;`